# How would I go about changing the integers within a method to Strings?

Tags: loops, class, object, methods

I am currently working on a dice game called "LCR" for java. I don't know how I would go about changing the integers within the roll() method into Strings. I know the program will not run as it is due to the int to String error, but we are supposed to return either a "D", "L", "C", or "R" depending on what the die rolls.

I did make the roll() method a String, however, that complicated the other classes.

I tried multiple methods on converting the integers to Strings, such as the toString method, the Integer.valueOf() method, and many more. I don't know if I have to make a separate method for this conversion, or if I should keep the roll() method as a String.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;

// Create class
public class Die_2
{
    private int faceDie = 1;

    // Create method: roll()
    // RETURN D, R, L, or C depending on roll results...
    public int roll ()
    {
        // Use random 
        Random randInt = new Random();
        int faceDie = randInt.nextInt(6) + 1;

        if (faceDie < 4.0/ 8.0) 
            faceDie = 4;
        else if (faceDie < 5.0/ 8.0)
            faceDie = 5;
        else if (faceDie < 6.0/ 8.0)
            faceDie = 6;    

        // Return D, L, C, R...
        if (faceDie == 1 || faceDie == 2 || faceDie == 3)
        {       
            return "D";
        }
        else if (faceDie == 4)
        {   
            return "L";
        }
        else if (faceDie == 5)
        {   
            return "C";
        }
        else 
        {   
            return "R";
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *first* thing to do is mark the method so that it returns a string.

And, given you're creating a random value between 1 and 6 inclusive, I'm not sure the code that does stuff when it's less than a half, or five eighths, or three quarters, is very useful :-) You should probably get rid of that.

Finally, you're better off creating the `randInt` object in a constructor somewhere rather than instantiating a new one every time you call the function.

Other than those three things, what you have should be fine, with a little code clean-up as well:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class HelloWorld {
    Random randInt;

    public HelloWorld() {
        randInt = new Random();
    }

    public String roll ()
    {
        int faceDie = randInt.nextInt(6) + 1;

        if (faceDie <= 3) return "D";
        if (faceDie == 4) return "L";
        if (faceDie == 5) return "C";
        return "R";
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
        System.out.println(hw.roll());
    }
}
```

---

Of course, you could simplify it *greatly* by just using the values `0` thru `5` and indexing into a string of the values you want. I wouldn't use that if there were a *lot* of choices, but six should be fine, and the `roll()` code then becomes (with everything else staying the same):

```
public String roll() {
    int index = randInt.nextInt(6);
    return "DDDLCR".substring(index, index + 1);
}
```